# in Hibernet 1 to many mapping done by using join column how write HQL query to create inner join using that join column

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table 1 `Tb_FileMaster` with the fields `(file_id file_name, file_path)`

file_id is join column attribute in other table

How can I select records associated with `MAX file_id` selected from second table

Answer (score 0):

In HQL it would look something like this:

```
select secondTable.* FROM Tb_FileDetails secondTable
join secondTable.tb_FileMaster firstTable
where firstTable.file_id = (select max(x.file_id) from Tb_FileMaster x)
```

Comment: Actully i  am stuck with POJO class where i can use parent class use mappedby=""parent"  and child has proprety JoinColumn so how i can write join query on that column is it possiable....